# Assembly in visual studio Print the value in registry

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

I have created a program in visual studio to move values in the registry but  i have no way of knowing whether the program actually worked since i cannot see the registr in visual studio 2017

I am running on visual studio 2017. I have a C++ Project that looks like this

```
extern "C" void doit();

void main()
{
    doit();
}
```

and thsi is what my assembly file looks like

```
.586
.model flat ,c
.stack 100h
.data

.code

doit proc

mov eax, 8
mov ebx, 4
mov ecx, 6
mov edx, 12

add eax, ebx
add eax, edx
sub eax, ecx
doit endp

end
```

I would now please like to print or message box the values in these registrys so that i can know if the program works. Thx for the help

Comment: I think (hope) you mean values in *registers*.  The [tag:windows-registry] key/value config database is something very different from CPU registers.

Comment: The easiest thing by far is to single-step your program in a debugger.  That's a lot easier than passing values to `printf`, especially because `call printf` destroys the values in all the call-clobbered registers (according to the calling convention.)  Debug-prints are clumsy in asm, but debuggers are *excellent* because the architectural state of the machine is small, and the source language exactly matches what the machine can single-step.

Comment: @PeterCordes i have tried but the registys do not seem to be in visual studio 2017. Any idea where i can find them?

Comment: *registers*, not *registries*.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register vs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registry.  But anyway, see the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for a couple links about using the debugger in VS.  It definitely has a registers pane. [Debugging ASM with Visual Studio - Register content will not display](//stackoverflow.com/q/46394685).  Hopefully it will even highlight which reg values changed after single-stepping, like other good debuggers.